Selecting unique rows of a dataframe when the duplicate values are swapped across multiple columns in R?
I am trying to use R to filter a dataframe based on two columns to select rows that are agnostic to which column of those two columns a value occurs in.
The input looks like this, with duplicates bolded. Note that the ID column does NOT contribute to uniqueness:



ID
Col_1
Col_2




1
A
A


1
A
B


1
A
C


1
B
A


1
B
B


1
B
C


2
C
B


2
C
C


2
C
D



I tried to filter by removing rows based on values of Col_2 that don't show up in Col_1 or vice versa, but that removes entirely too much. What I'd like the output to be is something like:



ID
Col_1
Col_2




1
A
A


1
A
B


1
A
C


1
B
B


1
B
C


2
C
C


2
C
D



I can't swap values between Col_1 and Col_2, because in the cases where there is no "duplication" it is relevant which column a given value appears in. It also doesn't matter whether, e.g., A B is selected over B A, just that only one is retained.

One way to solve your problem:
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  distinct(C1 = pmin(Col_1, Col_2), C2 = pmax(Col_1, Col_2), .keep_all=T) |> 
  select(-c(C1, C2))

  ID Col_1 Col_2
1  1     A     A
2  1     A     B
3  1     A     C
4  1     B     B
5  1     B     C
6  2     C     C
7  2     C     D

Or using built-in functions:
with(df, df[!duplicated(cbind(pmin(Col_1, Col_2), pmax(Col_1, Col_2))),])


Curious to see more concise approaches. We could pivot longer, sort, and combine the entries to determine distinct ones:
library(tidyverse)
tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Col_1, ~Col_2,
   1L,    "A",    "A",
   1L,    "A",    "B",
   1L,    "A",    "C",
   1L,    "B",    "A",
   1L,    "B",    "B",
   1L,    "B",    "C",
   2L,    "C",    "B",
   2L,    "C",    "C",
   2L,    "C",    "D"
  ) |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(row, ID)) |>
  arrange(ID, value) |>
  summarize(vals = paste(value, collapse = ", "), .by = c(ID, row)) |>
  distinct(vals, .keep_all = TRUE)

Result
     ID   row vals 
  <int> <int> <chr>
1     1     1 A, A 
2     1     2 A, B 
3     1     3 A, C 
4     1     5 B, B 
5     1     6 B, C 
6     2     8 C, C 
7     2     9 C, D


Comparing the present combinations with the combinations created by gtools::combinations. If we allow repeats ("AA", "BB" etc) we get the desired output.
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)

df %>% 
  filter(paste0(Col_1, Col_2) %in% apply(
    combinations(n = length(unique(c(Col_1, Col_2))), 
                 r = 2, 
                 v = unique(c(Col_1, Col_2)), 
                 repeats.allowed = TRUE), 1, paste, collapse=""))
  ID Col_1 Col_2
1  1     A     A
2  1     A     B
3  1     A     C
4  1     B     B
5  1     B     C
6  2     C     C
7  2     C     D

Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Col_1 = c(
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), Col_2 = c("A", "B",
"C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-9L))

